# regular expression pattern not matching with my string

Tags: regex

How can I rewrite  below regular expression

```
/((?:\+|00)[17](?: |\-)?|(?:\+|00)[1-9]\d{0,2}(?: |\-)?|(?:\+|00)1\-\d{3}(?: |\-)?)?(0\d|\([0-9]{3}\)|[1-9]{0,3})(?:((?: |\-)[0-9]{2}){4}|((?:[0-9]{2}){4})|((?: |\-)[0-9]{3}(?: |\-)[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{7}))/g
```

for matching with this pattern

```
+1(555)532-3455
```

Comment: `/\+1\(555\)532-3455/` would successfully **only** match `+1(555)532-3455`... though that's probably not what you want. You'll need to specify exactly what number you want to allow, and what numbers you don't want to allow, preferably showing a few examples of each.

Comment: Can you please update your question to explain what your expression is trying to do? It seems incredibly complicated for what you're trying to do. Did you just copy and paste it?

Comment: i get it from this link [https://www.regextester.com/1978]

Comment: A great tool for working with regular expressions is regex101.com.  Copy/paste your regex and test pattern there and take a look at what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression seems needlessly complicated for matching that string. You're trying to match the following aspects:

- a plus sign with a country code
- an area code wrapped in brackets
- the first 3 digits of the phone number
- a dash
- the last 4 digits of the phone number
- no spaces anywhere

To match this you only need

```
^\+[0-9]\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$
```

If you need to allow for optional spaces between the country code, area code and phone number you can add them to the expression.

```
^\+[0-9]\s?\([0-9]{3}\)\s?[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$
```

(I may have unnecessary escapes `\` in there)

Comment: when i try this '+1  (666)  545-6456' it returns false?

Comment: @federer That's because you've got spaces in your string. You only showed one string and it had no spaces, which is why I even made it a bullet point in 
what you're trying to match,

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do:

[`^\+?\d(?:\s*(?:\(|\-)?\s*)\d{3}(?:\s*(?:\)|\-)?\s*)(?:\d{3}(?:\s*\-?\s*)?\d{4})$`](https://regex101.com/r/jLIp4q/1/)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jLIp4q/1/) for some examples of what this regex can and can not match.